# Laravel get array find collection and delete all

Tags: sql, laravel

i need to get the id in the form of an array and delete it if they belong to user

```
   Events::where('user_id', auth()->id())->find([67,69])->delete();
```

when trying to delete, I get this error
[image: when trying to delete, I get this error]

Comment: Events::where('user_id', auth()->id())->whereIn('id',[67,69])->delete();

Comment: @JohnLobo Upvoted! I almost made an answer. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it in very simple way i think

```
Events::where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ->whereIn('id',[67,69])
    ->delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

After getting ids in a form of array, you may write code like this:

```
Events::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id())
        ->whereIn('id', [67,69])
        ->delete();
```

Here, you need to use `whereIn()` eloquent method as it takes array as a parameter instead of `find()`. You may use `find()` to retrieve single models or aggregates by their primary key.

For more details, follow the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#deleting-models-using-queries

Answer (score 0):

try

```php
Events::whereIn('id', [67, 69])
->get()
->each(function ($event) {
    Events::where('id', $event->id)->where('user_id', auth()->id())->delete();
})
```

AFAIK, you can't use `find` with array as the parameter.

Comment: Events::whereIn('id', [67, 69])
->get()
->each->delete();
would work as far as I know, no need for function.